# XSD element cardinality - how to model 'One of the fields is mandatory'

Tags: xml, xsd

In my XSD element, I have to make "one of the fields fieldA or filedB mandatory."

```
So far i have this:


<xsd:complexType name="Test">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="fieldA" maxOccurs="1"    minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="fieldB" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

How to set cardinality for this 2 fields so that one is mandatory?

Thank you very much for your time and effort!

Comment: Nine questions, and only three have been marked as answered. Want more responses? Start marking the best answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `<xsd:choice>` instead of `<xsd:sequence>` and drop the `minOccurs="0"`

Sample code that requires exactly either one of the fields

```
<xsd:complexType name="Test">
    <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="fieldA"/>
        <xsd:element name="fieldB"/>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

If you want to require that there is `<fieldA>` or `<fieldB>` or both elements *in whatever order*, then use this

```
<xsd:complexType name="Test">
    <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="fieldA"/>
            <xsd:element name="fieldB" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="fieldB"/>
            <xsd:element name="fieldA" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

If you want to require that there is `<fieldA>` or `<fieldB>` or both elements *and preserve the order* (`<fieldA>` before `<fieldB>`), then you can simplify the structure a bit.

```
<xsd:complexType name="Test">
    <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="fieldA"/>
            <xsd:element name="fieldB" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="fieldB"/>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this useful answer. Still i have one problem.

Comment: I need to make both fields type string and limit length to 10.   When i copied your code, in my Eclipse visual editor, type was 'anytype'. I try to change type from anyType to string and i got error:                                                          "XSD: The element '#fieldA' may not have both type 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyType'
and type 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string' "

Comment: @reg The type is `anyType` because the `<xsd:element>` definition doesn't have a `<xsd:simpleType>` or `<xsd:complexType>` child that defines the type of that element or a `type` attribute that refers to a globally defined type. In your case you need to create a simpleType with a `maxLength="10"` restriction. Examples can be found on various Schema tutorials, for example on these two http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/xml/user-derived-simple-types.html and http://www.learn-xml-schema-tutorial.com/Simple-Type-Elements.cfm

Answer (score 1):

The *choice* element can help you:

```
<xs:complexType name="Test">
    <xs:choice>
         <xs:element name="fieldA" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>
         <xs:element name="fieldB" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

For more: http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/el_choice.asp